# How do I rewrite this url with htaccess / mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how do I rewrite this url with .htaccess mod_rewrite

```
http://55.100.10.66:81/var/class/tag?isAjax=true&id=189&key=eJwVxzEOwjAMB&callback=_prototypeJSONPCallback_0
```

to

```
http://55.100.10.66:81/index.php/var/class/tag?isAjax=true&id=189&key=eJwVxzEOwjAMB&callback=_prototypeJSONPCallback_0
```

Amongst a lot of things I tried the below which doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^var/class/tag(.*) /index.php/var/class/tag$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Thanks!

This is the solution

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/var/class/tag(.*)
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING from RewriteRule. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(var/class/tag/?)$ /index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks! will try that too... just found a working solution.. will bump your post anyway.